# How to implement dynamic loading inside an Intel SGX Enclave?

Tags: c++, cloud, intel, sgx, enclave

Because no standard library can be used inside Intel SGX enclave. How to implement dynamic loading inside an Enclave? For example, I have functions `foo1()` and `foo2()`  in a file with .so extension type.

I need to dynamically load a function inside the Enclave. Then, main function outside Enclave can call the function loaded.

App.cpp

`status = ecall_dynamicLoading(enclave_id,func); 
// func is a function pointer loaded from .so
// for example, func = &foo1;`

Enclave.cpp

`ecall_dynamicLoading(func){
    (*func)(/* some inputs */);
}`

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Too broad. Please narrow your question to *a single specific thing* that you are having problems with. Also, please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

By Intel's own documentation, you can not load a shared_object (.so) inside the ENCLAVE. You need to turn it into a static library.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/708963
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/708964

Even then, the static library has a lot of limitations.